# Is there any tool to execute Postgis-like queries without a postgres server?

Tags: postgis, spatialite, linear-referencing

I would like to know if there is any way/tool of using geoprocesing queries like the ones you use with POSTGIS but without the need of having an actual database server available.

The particular aplication in this case is the linear referencing of arbitrary points over a set of linestrings representing a road network. Basically I'm using a "static" postgis database (static in the sense that there is just an initial load and no further updates/deletes/inserts).

I've heard of Spatialite but I'm not sure what kind of infrastructure do you need to do this kind of operations or if it has the same capabilities than the POSTGIS extension.

The actual aplication is being written in c#, although more than native libraries, I would be interest in running queries with little modifications, as I already have previous knowledge on POSTGIS queries.

Comment: Read a list of supported functions in Spatialite from https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html. Spatialite-gui program is good for demonstrating the capabilities of Spatialite.

Comment: I've edited this into the answer, hope you don't mind. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As you said, you could use embedded instance of `spatiallite`. In that case, it will starts together with your application, and keep all the data as one file, somewhere with your app resources.
2. You could try `JavaTopologySuit` (or it's analogue for other platform). There are no such things like SQL queries, but it could create `Spatial indexes`, quickly select geometry from such indexes, and process geometries.

Answer (score 1):

[H2GIS](http://www.h2gis.org) may fit with your needs as it does not require any installation (except Java) and is really close to PostGIS (SFSQL compatible).

In a nutshell: [H2GIS](http://www.h2gis.org) is to H2 as PostGIS is to PostgreSQL.

[H2GIS](http://www.h2gis.org) adds support for (MULTI)POINT, (MULTI)LINESTRING and (MULTI)POLYGON types, the functions specified by the OpenGIS Simple Features Implementation Specification for SQL and additional spatial functions including graph analysis package [H2Network](http://www.h2gis.org/docs/dev/h2network/). [H2GIS](http://www.h2gis.org) can be embedded into any java/groovy/android software.

[H2Network](http://www.h2gis.org/docs/dev/h2network/) has been initially designed for road network analysis.

note: I'm one of the authors of this library

Comment: One of the function I would need to use is ST_LineLocatePoint. That does  not seem to be implemented (yet?)

Comment: This function does not exist in H2GIS alone (not SFSQL) but you can compute the same result using ST_ProjectPoint and ST_Distance.

Comment: If you really need the length fraction you have to use ST_LineIntersector(line, point) or ST_Split then take the first part with ST_GeometryN and finally compute the fraction length using ST_Length.

Comment: you can use ST_ClosestPoint instead of ST_ProjectPoint, this function is available in H2GIS and PostGIS.